# Fixing CA2123 in UnitTest for interface defined in WindowsCE project

Tags: c#, unit-testing, windows-ce

I'm receiving an error from FxCop when building my project and unit tests. The error displayed is something like `Mocks\MockAudio.cs (36): Microsoft.Security : Add the following security attribute to 'MockAudio.InitializeAudio()' in order to match a LinkDemand on base method 'IAudio.InitializeAudio()':  'SecurityCriticalAttribute'.`

However, my interface is defined in a WindowsCE .NET 3.5 project like so:

```
public interface IAudio : IDisposable
{
    void InitializeAudio();
    void PlayAudio(int successDuration, int successFrequency);
}
```

And my unit test is written in a seperate class library:

```
public class MockAudio : IAudio
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    public void InitializeAudio()
    {
    }

    public void PlayAudio(int successDuration, int successFrequency)
    {
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
    }
}
```

As far as I can tell I haven't specified a LinkDemand on the IAudio interface! Adding `SecurityCritical` like so:

```
public class MockAudio : IAudio
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    [SecurityCritical]
    public void InitializeAudio()
    {
    }

    public void PlayAudio(int successDuration, int successFrequency)
    {
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
    }
}
```

Doesn't solve the issue. Has anyone else come across this? Searching on-line hasn't returned answers and talks a lot about C++/C# wheras in my case I'm working purely in C#. Thanks.

Comment: What unit test framework are you using (I ask because MSTEST would want things like `[TestClass]` attributes)?  Is this in VS '08?  It sure feels like you have desktop assembly references, not device references.

Comment: This is in VS'08 - IAudio is defined in a Smart Device project targetting Windows CE, the MockAudio class is defined in Test project so that it can run on my desktop.

I do use MSTEST and have test classes and test methods that use MockAudio, MockAudio itself doesn't have the [TestClass] attribute though as it doesn't contain tests itself.

Comment: Ah, so the mock implementation is in a desktop assembly that references a CF assembly. The theory behind this says it should work, but I don't think reality bridges that.  You're likely best served by having a separate FFx build of your code that you want to test on the desktop.  It's really just a new project file that includes *.cs

Comment: The test project references the Windows CE assembly without issue and and tests all work fine. I should have mentioned in my original post that it's FxCop that throws the errors but in order to have a green build I should fix that. Part of the build acceptance criteria is having a high level of code coverage - the tests therefore have to test the Windows CE build, otherwise having a Desktop target project may have solved my issue. Thanks!